# Identify unknown component on AC LED bulb PCB

Tags: led, pcb, components

I'm trying to put this back together. The part that's broken off is a mystery, saying only '952' and cutting it open, I'm not sure.

What is the 952 part, please? And is it still usable? Thank you.[image]

Comment: L means inductor on pcb labeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component with the legs broken off is an unshielded drum ferrite core inductor. You'd have to find the ends of the wires and attach to them to save it (not easy) and mount it somehow.

Value is probably 9,500uH (9.5mH).

Comment: Wow, thank you. I'd like to replace it. Can you recommend an online store? I'd like to buy a few of each, tho not a 10 pack, like on Amazon. Thanks again.

Comment: You're in Texas, so you could try Mouser.

Comment: That's a huge tip. I've browsed the site, briefly, but free overnight shipping in TX? Wow.